# Trouble calling or assigning variable value in React Native Class

Tags: react-native, variables, setstate

I have the following class in React Native.  As can be seen I have some defined 'state' variables and a 'componentDidMount' call which is designed to retrieve previously stored variables using the 'AsyncStorage' tool.

```
export default class Cast extends Component {
state = {
  admin: false,
  isPublishing: false,
  userComment: "",
  hasPermission: false,
  paused: true,
  _email: false,
  _name: false,
  _pword: false,
};


getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
console.log("value variable AFTER getKey: " + value);
    this.setState({ _email: value });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getKey();
}

onPressBtn = () => {
console.log("EMAIL value variable AFTER getKey: " + this.state._email)  //this should show the value AFTER the retrieval from storage...correct?
};

//...
```

The console.log statement following the 'AsyncStorage.getItem' successfully displays the variable "value" as being retrieved from the storage (example "me@gmail.com").  However I am greatly confused on how to assign this variable and display it.  The "this.setState({ _email: value });" is either not functional or I am using incorrect syntax to display the value for the "_email" variable.  I have attempted the following:

```
console.log("_email variable AFTER getKey: " + _email);
console.log("_email variable AFTER getKey: " + this._email);
console.log("_email variable AFTER getKey: " + {_email});
console.log("_email variable AFTER getKey: " + this.state._email);
```

None of the above correctly return the value of the "_email" variable.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is the 'setState' assignment not correct...?  I simply want to retrieve any values that are in storage (as "value") and then assign them to the appropriate variables defined in the 'state'.  Any advice greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on `when` you have tried to access the state variable. If you did the following:

```js
getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    console.log("value variable AFTER getKey: " + value);
    this.setState({ _email: value });
    console.log(this.state._email)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}
```

Then, this will print `false`, which is the default in your state. Setting the state will cause a rerender. The new value will be available afterwards.

Consider the following snippet.

```js
getKey = async () => {
    try {
      var value = "test"
      console.log("value variable AFTER getKey: " + value)
      this.setState({ _email: value })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error)
    }
  }

 ...

  render() {
    console.log("HELLO VALUE", this.state._email)
    return <></>
  }
```

We will notice the following outputs printed to the console.

```sh
LOG  HELLO VALUE false
LOG  value variable AFTER getKey: test
LOG  HELLO VALUE test
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I only need to access the 'new' variable (set after the 'setState' is called) so they become available in other functions within the class, it seems your post implies the variable will update only after a 'render' function is executed.  I am assuming I can access the current value (using "this.state._email") within another function (as in my edit above named "onPressBtn"...not only from a button or console.log within the render)...correct?  Again I thank you for your information.

Comment: setState is async in the componentDidMount func, so you cannot get this.state._email after the setState immediately,but you can access the value of this.state._email at the next tick.

Comment: OK thank you for that information...the next tick or two is fine...as long as it is updated and made available to other functions in the class.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare your state object in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = { 
  admin: false,
  isPublishing: false,
  userComment: "",
  hasPermission: false,
  paused: true,
  _email: false,
  _name: false,
  _pword: false,
};
  
//Other codes

}
```

Also when referring to a state, you want to use:
eg. you're trying to get the email stored in the state

```
this.state._email

//setting states
this.setState({_email: "newEmail"})
```

Comment: This works without using a constructor. We can initialize a state in a class component as a `class property`.

Comment: Thank you for your post Mr Ezeh, can you explain what is the difference from what had in my original post and the addition of a 'constructor/super'...I am not sure what the difference in syntax accomplishes...or if usage of a 'constructor' is still currently common...or more 'obsolete'...?